# Umbraco 7 Dynamic Template Block contents

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Hi i need some help with umbraco to define dynamic block template. I've the structure described in the image below

[image: TemplateScreenshot]

i want to create a dinamic structure for the investor area like in the next screenshot

[image]

i try to create benefit template as child of investor template and investor template child of Investors template. In that way my customer can dinamically add or remove benefit from investor and investor from Investors. I watched all umbraco tv videos but i don't know how to solve this problem! I'm searching in something similar to:

```
        @foreach(var page in CurrentPage.Children){
            <li>!!!@RenderChildTemplate(page)!!!</li>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way! Simple i don't need any template! only partial view that contains block code! and then i can use @html.partial to render them! it was really simple and in the correct mvc way!